# Adding actions to an Android Wear Activity

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I would like to be able to have the user swipe over a screen and tap the `"Open on Phone"` action from within my Android Wear app, but I cannot seem to find how to make this happen.

The click and what not is not the issue, I cannot figure out how to add the actions, my `activity` doesn't allow the user to swipe over.

*Any ideas on how this is accomplished*?

The key here is that the actions are in the `Activity`, not in the Notification which has plenty of documentation.

For an exact example of what I want, look at the world clock app with no clocks setup. It will say swipe to add, swiping over reveals an add action inside the blue circle background. This is the behavior I'd like to see.

Comment: did you check the tutorial? actions on android wear are just like notification actions

Comment: There is plently of info on how to do it with notifications, but I am inside of an Activity at this point. I was under the assumption that they would behave similar to the actionbar actions, but so far that is not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part what you're going to want in wear are notifications.  These offer you the actions that you're used to seeing on the watch like the swipe to the right to interact.  These actions are just actions that have been added to the notification.

In order to do this in your own Activity on wear you need to implement it yourself just like you would on a phone.  I'd recommend starting with a ViewPager and going from there.

Comment: Really? The apps with multiple pages are simply different fragments? I had expected the actionbar actions to be handled as the notification actions did.

Comment: They don't need to be whole fragments since the types of interactions you're going to want to do on your watch are going to be pretty limited but they are separate views within a view pager.

Comment: It's the kind of thing where using their framework buys you a lot and when you choose to opt out you get much more flexibility but it's a lot more work.

Comment: Is there anything in their framework that would be useful for this? I just need to have an open on phone for configuration page. Insetactivoty and confirmationactivoty dont seem to be it